# iPhone taking picture leads to white screen after taking picture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, image

I have this code to take a picture in my iPhone application:

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])  {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }
    else{
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

Then I have this other controller to manage the picture taken:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    [picker.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageTaken.image = image;
    NSLog(@"saved!");
}
```

I tried to launch the app on my iPhone 4 (iOS 4.something) and after taking a picture and clicking on "use" I get a white screen. When testing the app directly on another phone, launched directly from XCode (iOS 5 this time) to check the Log, I tap on "use" but then nothing happens and the Log is correctly printed.

Do you know what's going on? I thought that the screen of the picture was not closing, but I call dismissModalViewController....

Thanks,

Masiar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dismiss the modal view controller in this fashion,

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And it is better to use `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` as the other method is being deprecated.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageTaken.image = (UIImage *)[info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
}
```

Comment: How does exactly `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES]` works? My app is a bit messy and I have that code in my main view, even if so does this remove the view of the picture and let me continue with my App?

Comment: It works exactly as mentioned [`here`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW30). It will dismiss the modal view controller presented by `self`. If called within the modal view controller, the message is passed back to the view controller that presented it.

Comment: I'm also getting a white screen occasionally, but I'm using up-to-date functions to handle the ImagePicker.  I doubt that anything he's doing here is the cause.